# Getting content out of WebView In a unit test Android, using java script

Tags: javascript, android, unit-testing

I have been able to get content out of WebView using javascript and loadUrl() method having specified an interface thats called from javascript string that is injected into WebView.The problem is that this only works for me when the loadUrl() method is present in onPageFinished() method in the WebView client. What I want to do is I want to get the content out of the WebView (with the content already loaded). The WebView is in an activity instrumentation test case and I can for instance use findAll() method and that works fine. For some reason I can not use loadUrl() and get the desired behaviour (which is injecting javascript and getting content out of the WebView with a help of an interface).

PLease help.

Thanks

Pawel

EDIT:
Just adding code to show what I am doing exactly:

Yes I understand that but my problem is that I am trying to do it within a test case this way:

```
public void testWebView() throws Exception {

    solo.sleep(3000); // wait for views to load on the screen
    WebView a=null;
    ArrayList<View> views = solo.getCurrentViews(); // I am using solo object to get views for the screen currently loaded
    for(View s:views)
    {
        if (s instanceof WebView)
        {
            a = (WebView)s; // this is where I get my WebView
        }
    }

    Instrumentation inst = getInstrumentation();

    inst.runOnMainSync(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
         int d =a.findAll("something"); // this method runs fine on the object and i get the desired result

         WebSettings settings = a.getSettings(); 
         settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

         a.loadUrl("javascript:document.location = document.getElementById('google').getAttribute('href')"); // this javascript is never executed and that is my problem

        }
    });


}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can inject javascript in a loaded page much the same way you can do it in desktop browsers - via inline javascript entered into navigation bar.

1. Bind some Java object so that it can be called from Javascript with WebView:

   ```
   addJavascriptInterface(javaObjectExposed, "JSname")
   ```
2. Force execute javascript within an existing page by

   ```
   WebView.loadUrl("javascript:window.JSname.passData("some data from page");");
   ```

Comment: Yes I understand that but have a look at the update to my code please It shows what I am trying to do exactly. Thank you.

Comment: Does this URL produce a redirect?

Comment: No I does not Its all fine when I run it in a browser or if I run it within the app rather then the test case. I mean the javascript just clicks on a link on the page. Also any other url does not load either.

Comment: Is the original content loaded via `loadData()`? Content loaded this way can not access network, e.g. load other URLs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadData(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)

Comment: The original content is loaded via loadUrl()

Comment: OK I fixed the problem. In the Test case I was calling this method on the main thread (runOnMainSync()) that was the problem since it was blocking the execution of loadUrl() method. Thank you very much anyway!